# How do I select all rows whose values exceed a given sum?

Tags: postgresql

Lets say I have a table

```
name | val
------------
a    |10
b    |10
c    |20
d    |30
```

and I also have a user input of `25`. How do I select all the rows so that the sum of `val` is one row over `25`. So for a user input of 25 I would get back the first three rows which give me a value of `40`. The equivalent code for what I'm trying to do is

```
total = 0
user_input = 25
while total < user_input and rows_by_val_asc_iterator.has_next():
    row = rows_by_val_asc_iterator.next()
    total = total + row.val
```

Comment: Use `OVER` to create a column which contains the cumulative sum.  Then select rows where the cumulative sum is less than your user input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this using something called a "window function". Basically it lets you have a running total. Select rows til the sum exceeds your desired total.

For example, try something like this:

```
select name, val
  from (
    select name, val, (sum(val) over (order by val, name)) as total
    from vals
  ) as t
  where total - val < 25
```